# MVC typing URL doesn't work, links do

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC site. I have a form submit (it submits no data in this case) that triggers an Action in the Controller and returns a View. If I refresh, it asks to resubmit the form and works. If I click on the URL in the "awesome bar" or whatever, and hit Enter, I get a 404 resource cannot be found error.

The URL displayed is /pts/reports/subject. I don't get what's happening. Any suggestions?

Action in Controller:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Subject()
    {
        return View(new SubjectModel());
    }
```

Form:

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Subject", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-a"}))
       { %>
        <fieldset>
            <h5 class="section-header">Subject</h5>
            <div class="positionbottom">
                <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="csv" class="right">Web</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    <% } %>
```

MapRoute:

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "Pts_Reports",
        "pts/reports/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Reports", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action expects a POST:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

If you submit a form with a POST method (which you are... `FormMethod.Post`), then it will work as expected.  Which you've observed.  However, just clicking a link or manually entering the address is a *GET* request, not a *POST* request.  So there's no matching action.  Thus, a 404 error.

In order you accept any request, just remove that `AcceptVerbs` usage.  But keep in mind that GET requests won't contain form data.  The action you show in the code doesn't *use* any form data, so that's fine.  (But then why are you posting a form to it?)

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. That makes sense.

The form thing is probably going to be used in the future, but currently isn't.